# Cant login to remote site with CURL

Tags: php, curl, authentication

I always get an error: "Either email and/or password do not match or the user may not exist."

I then tried passing the parameters manually through the URL, and the same error occurs. However, I can normally log in when I type in the details inside the form itself.

Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT: Is this maybe because when I append the password in URL, it returns an error because my password is encrypted inside the database, and it compares it to the string I sent inside the URL? That's the only explanation I can think of...

Answer (score 1):

Right now the only parameter you are sending is the `emailaddress` field with `"myemail@email.com$Password=mypass123"` as value, I guess

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'EmailAddress=myemail@email.com$Password=mypass123');
```

should probably be:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'EmailAddress=myemail@email.com&Password=mypass123');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not see the difference between those two lines :/

Comment: You're absolutely right (clumsy me). However, there's still a problem, now I get a page which says: TEMPORARY REDIRECT - The document moved here (link)

Comment: Oops! found it, just had to enable CURL option to follow redirects :) works now